# How foreign key in a child table, can automatically get the value it actually has in the parent table

Tags: php, mysql

Can anybody tell whether a foreign key in a child table, can automatically get the value it actually has in the parent table?
I has two tables student and course table.Student SSC is foreign key in course.I am inserting data correctly into student table.But It gives me an error when I insert data into course table?Any suggestions?
Values of variables are got via post method of form.

```
$query1=mysql_query("INSERT INTO course VALUES('','$subject','$total','$attendce','$ssn')")or die(mysql_error());
```

This is error I am getting....

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`cast_db`.`course`, CONSTRAINT `course_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`cnic`)
>   REFERENCES `student` (`cnic`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: What kind of error? How are you trying to insert data? Please include these details so we can help you. We're not mind readers you know!

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, then I suggest that you should using last_insert_index() to retrieve the index. Otherwise, please provide more details, and sql, if possible.

Comment: What language / framework / situation are you working with?  Straight SQL?  There are sometimes ways you can do things like that but it all depends what you are really asking.  You have not given us enough information to help you.

Comment: @Madara Uchiha I had provided code in edited question.Please have a look on it.

Comment: what's the table schema? is the first column the foreign key?

Comment: NO the last one is FK.First one is PK and its auto increment.I have composite PK in Parent table(id AUTO INCREMENT and SSC).

Answer (score 4):

That's not how foreign keys work. You have to create a parent record first, get that record's ID (whatever the primary key happens to be) value, and then use that value in your child record insertions.

Remember - a parent table can have MANY records. There is no way for a database to know which of those records is the parent of a new child record. You **HAVE** to explicitly say that "this new child record has parent X".

Comment: Yeah it sounds good.I am inserting record in my parent table then I am inserting record in child table.(SSC is my PK in Parent and FK in child table).But its not working.

Comment: @Naeem Marc B's answer is correct and all you need to correct the sequence of your SQL commands.  If you are having trouble with the SQL to insert these records, you need to post the SQL you are using along with the errors you are getting with that SQL.